# Stop AWS aurora database using lambda function using python 2.7

Tags: lambda, amazon-aurora

I used the below lambda function to stop my rds aurora database. But it always ends in an error "RDS' object has no attribute **'stop_db_cluster'**". can anyone help me here;

```
import sys
import botocore
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    lambdaFunc = boto3.client('lambda')
    print ('Trying to get Environment variable')
    try:
        funcResponse = lambdaFunc.get_function_configuration(
            FunctionName='RDSInstanceStop'
        )
        DBinstance = funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']
        print ('Stoping RDS service for DBInstance : ' + DBinstance)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)    
    try:
        response = client.stop_db_cluster(
            DBClusterIdentifier='DBInstanceName'
        )
        print ('Success :: ' )
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)    
    return
    {
        'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
    }
```

---

i am using the role - lambda-start-stop-rds my policy details - 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:ResetDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DescribeEngineDefaultParameters",
                "rds:CreateOptionGroup",
                "rds:CreateDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:PurchaseReservedDBInstancesOffering",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "rds:ModifyDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:AddSourceIdentifierToSubscription",
                "rds:DownloadDBLogFilePortion",
                "rds:CopyDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:AddRoleToDBCluster",
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
                "rds:ModifyDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttribute",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots",
                "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot",
                "rds:DescribeDBSecurityGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "rds:PromoteReadReplica",
                "rds:StartDBInstance",
                "rds:DeleteDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:DescribeReservedDBInstances",
                "rds:CreateDBSnapshot",
                "rds:DescribeValidDBInstanceModifications",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot",
                "rds:DeleteDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions",
                "rds:ModifyDBCluster",
                "rds:CreateDBClusterSnapshot",
                "rds:DeleteDBParameterGroup",
                "rds:DescribeCertificates",
                "rds:CreateDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute",
                "rds:RemoveTagsFromResource",
                "rds:DescribeOptionGroups",
                "rds:AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
                "rds:CreateEventSubscription",
                "rds:ModifyOptionGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot",
                "rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions",
                "rds:DescribeDBSubnetGroups",
                "rds:DescribePendingMaintenanceActions",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameterGroups",
                "rds:DescribeReservedDBInstancesOfferings",
                "rds:DeleteOptionGroup",
                "rds:FailoverDBCluster",
                "rds:DeleteEventSubscription",
                "rds:RemoveSourceIdentifierFromSubscription",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeEngineDefaultClusterParameters",
                "rds:RevokeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
                "rds:DescribeDBParameters",
                "rds:DescribeEventCategories",
                "rds:ModifyCurrentDBClusterCapacity",
                "rds:DeleteDBCluster",
                "rds:ResetDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBClusterToPointInTime",
                "rds:DescribeEvents",
                "rds:AddTagsToResource",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshotAttributes",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterParameters",
                "rds:DescribeEventSubscriptions",
                "rds:CopyDBSnapshot",
                "rds:CopyDBClusterSnapshot",
                "rds:ModifyEventSubscription",
                "rds:DescribeDBLogFiles",
                "rds:StopDBInstance",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "rds:CopyOptionGroup",
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshotAttributes",
                "rds:DeleteDBClusterSnapshot",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "rds:CreateDBCluster",
                "rds:CreateDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:RebootDBInstance",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterSnapshots",
                "rds:DescribeOptionGroupOptions",
                "rds:DownloadCompleteDBLogFile",
                "rds:DeleteDBClusterParameterGroup",
                "rds:ApplyPendingMaintenanceAction",
                "rds:CreateDBInstanceReadReplica",
                "rds:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusterParameterGroups",
                "rds:ModifyDBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]

### }

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:904108119046:function:RDSInstanceStop"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 2):

I had to re-write the lambda function with Runtime Python 3.7:

```
import botocore
import boto3

rdsId = 'data-cluster-d9xka2hfg766'

def stopRDS():
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    instances = rds.describe_db_clusters( DBClusterIdentifier=rdsId)

    status = instances.get('DBClusters')[0].get('Status')

    if status == 'available':    
        resp = rds.stop_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier=rdsId)
        print('Requested to stop rds: ' + str(rdsId))  
    else:
        print('RDS ' + str(rdsId) + ' is ' + str(status))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    stopRDS()
    return 'Stopped environment.'
```

Comment: This is probably the correct answer and should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue

From https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1723

> Looks like these operations were recently added and the lambda runtime
>   may not have the latest version of boto3, meaning the operation isn't
>   available. You'll need to bundle a newer version of the SDK with your
>   lambda package. Here's some docs on doing that:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Thanks for your update. But i researched further and found that i was using python 2.7 and when i changed to python 3.7 it worked.  But now i am getting the below error, can you please help me here;

Comment: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the StopDBCluster operation: User: arn:aws:sts::904108119046:assumed-role/lambda-start-stop-rds/RDSInstanceStop is not authorized to perform: rds:StopDBCluster on resource: arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-2:904108119046:cluster:dbinstancename
END RequestId: 38b48bd1-f818-11e8-81fb-4b70f65dc16d

Comment: This is my role details;

Comment: Need to revise the role policy to include StopDBCluster in the allowed section